# Can Discord Bot have a gmail account?

Tags: discord.py

I have a question, for the discord API in python, is it possible for the discord bot to have a discord account, thus I will be able to add the discord bot as a friend?

Answer (score 1):

You can't send friend requests to bots.
But however, it's possible to use your discord account token instead of the bot's one, then you would be able to send friend requests, but this behavior is called self-botting and is against the Discord TOS